# I want to traverse arraylist using get() method. So I pass the counter variable but its value cannot comes in sequence during incement & decrement

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist

I am working on this code,  So it has arraylist and m. auto() method returns the arraylist(values came from the database).So I have next and back button and I want to traverse the array one by one so I am using get method to do that and I pass the count variable as argument, so whenever that next or back button click I want to increment and decrement value by one. In this code increment operation works perfect but when I click back button (decrement) after doing increment the value of count variable change to 0. can anyone solve this problem?

```
package controller;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import model.AptUserModel;
import model.Entity;
import view.AptUserView;

public class AptUserController implements ActionListener 
{
    //for mvc
    AptUserView v;
    AptUserModel m=new AptUserModel();
    int count=0;
    public AptUserController(AptUserView v) 
    {
        this.v=v;
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg) 
    {
        Entity e=new Entity();
        ArrayList<Entity> a=new ArrayList<>();
        if(arg.getSource()==v.next)
        {
            //this method returns arraylist that comes from database
        a=m.auto();
            //for getting elements from arraylist one by one
            e=a.get(count);
            count++;
            System.out.println("count = "+count);
            v.que.setText(e.getQue());
            v.a.setText(e.getA());
            v.b.setText(e.getB());
            v.c.setText(e.getC());
            v.d.setText(e.getD());
        }
        else if(arg.getSource()==v.back)    
        {
            //this method returns arraylist that comes from database
                a=m.auto();
            //whenever I print count variable value it becomes 0 and throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
                System.out.println(count);
                count--;
                e=a.get(count);
                v.que.setText(e.getQue());
                v.a.setText(e.getA());
                v.b.setText(e.getB());
                v.c.setText(e.getC());
                v.d.setText(e.getD());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare count variable as static. May be that will help.